# MSSticker image from remote url with lazy loading (add loader)

Tags: ios, swift, lazy-loading, mssticker, msstickerview

I want to load Stickers from the server using remote URL, I have found a solution for that from following post.

[Creating a MSSticker with a remote image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086845/creating-a-mssticker-with-a-remote-image)

But now i want to load sticker image with lazy loading, can i add loader in each sticker cell until image load from remote url.

Comment: Hi, according to the link you mentioned, we can't directly provide a remote url for stickers, so we have to download it locally and give a local URL. So you might as well set a placeholder image until your sticker image is downloaded, and on completion of download, you can set the new image as your sticker.

Comment: Might not be what your looking for but you can use Nuke, allows you to use a placeholder and even a default image for images that might fail to load. https://github.com/kean/Nuke

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can show loader on each cell and hit the remote url to load the image.

[Async image loading from url inside a UITableView cell - image changes to wrong image while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663618/async-image-loading-from-url-inside-a-uitableview-cell-image-changes-to-wrong][1])

Comment: I am not discussing about UIimage view but i want to add loader with MSSticker